# HDFS bytes read and written by a Job launched through YARN

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I was wondering if there is anyway of checking the number of HDFS bytes read or written by an Spark application launched through YARN. For example, if I check the jobs completed in YARN:

```
Total number of applications (application-types: [] and states: [NEW, NEW_SAVING, SUBMITTED, ACCEPTED, RUNNING, FINISHED, FAILED, KILLED]):2
            Application-Id      Application-Name        Application-Type          User       Queue               State         Final-State         Progress                        Tracking-URL
application_1451137492021_0002  com.abrandon.upm.GenerateRandomText                SPARK    alvarobrandon      default            FINISHED           SUCCEEDED             100%                                 N/A
```

The idea is to be able to monitor the number of bytes that application_1451137492021_0002  has read or written. I have check the datanode logs but I can only find traces of non mapreduce jobs and of course no trace of this particular application.